# Is there a way to trigger the Loyalty Bonus for having the first game, on Linux?

Tags: borderlands-2, linux, borderlands-the-pre-sequel

Is there a way to trigger the Loyalty Bonus for having the first game, on Linux?

I assumed it just checked for the existence of the first game's saves in the same place that the rewarding game stores its saves, assuming that the checking uses the rewarding game's save location as a starting point

But copying my Borderlands save folder to .local/share/aspyr-media, didn't seem to do it?

So, is there a way to get the Loyalty Bonus for BL1 for BL2 and PreSequel, on Linux?

---

Actually, what does it take to trigger the full Loyalty on Windows? I installed PreSequel, 2, and have a save file for 1 on my Windows machine, and I only get 10 Moonstones and the Bullpup... Installing GOTY 1 to see if anything changes.

Comment: Try submitting a request to Aspyr: https://support.aspyr.com/hc/en-us/requests/new They ought to know.

Comment: @DanMan - They need me to make an account..  Thanks, but no thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank, you [Sinatr](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/135338/sinatr), for your comments on my other question, [Does the Steam version not come with the Day One Patch?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/371941/does-the-steam-version-not-come-with-the-day-one-patch)

For at least the PreSequel, the only reason having the save in that spot *didn't* work, was because I already booted up the game once.

That created a profile.bin, inside the savegames folder, storing the Loyalty and Badass Info. Once I removed it, booted up again, and made a new character, I got both Loyalty Guns, 30 Moonstones, and 500 Badass Points.

Although, the messages seem to have a typo, saying I only got 1 gun. Ah well.

Just making this answer so people have one. I'd happily upvote and green check an answer by Sinatr, if they made one...