# Does the Steam version not come with the Day One Patch?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

Does the Steam version not come with the Day One Patch, and that's why I'm not receiving 30 moonstones while having installed and made a save for both the first and second game?

Or it only checks on first boot, and I have to totally reinstall?

Or do I get 10 Moonstones and the Bullpup initially, then 20 more Moonstones and other stuff later on??

Comment: Try to actually run those previous versions at least once to trigger cloud synchronization and download saves. Afaik loyality rewards are given by detecting presense of saves.

Comment: @Sinatr - Opened both 1 and 2 and started a new game in them, with save. Then made a Nisha. Still only 10 Moonstones, and a Bullpup.

Comment: See [this page](https://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands/comments/2jti9h/getting_the_wrong_loyalty_bonus/), once you get reward it won't re-trigger again. You have to delete profile.bin.

Comment: @Sinatr - You can post those as answers...

Comment: @Sinatr - Especially since it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you only suspected patch issues due to lacking Loyalty Bonuses, as [another answer says](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/372072/108916), the issue was that you had booted up the game before.

Deleting the profile.bin as the now deleted @Sinatr, a.k.a user135338, suggested though [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands/comments/2jti9h/getting_the_wrong_loyalty_bonus/) in a comment, to reset the game's knowledge, allowed all the Loyalty Rewards as it should be.